# Asyncio Python : Using an infinite loop for producer, and let the consumers process when producer is waiting TCP stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

It is the first time that I post here so sorry if everything is not perfect.

The situation is the following :
I send some bursts of NMEA sentences from a client to a server over a TCP connection using socket in python.

I want to avoid any latency for sending and receiving NMEA sentences. Therefore, I want the receiving of NMEA sentences from the server side to be the priority, and use the time between the bursts of data to process the sentences and store it in a database.

Therefore I wanted to use asyncio (python 3.8) to continuously add the NMEA sentences to a asyncio.queue and let the process of these sentences to happen while the function to receive data from the socket is waiting for new data.

The pseudo-code of my main loop inside my class is the following :

```
    #Producer
    async def _read_comms(self,queue):
        """ """
        while True:
            comm_nmea = await self.DataPort.receive_line_async()
            await queue.put(comm_nmea)

    #Consumers
    async def _process_comms(self,queue):
        """ """
        while True:
            comm_nmea = await queue.get()
            data = await self.Parser.parse_comm_nmea(comm_nmea=comm_nmea)
            await self._data_to_db(data)

    #main
    async def receive(self):
        """ """
        self.Logger.info("Start collecting")
        while(True):
            queue = asyncio.Queue()
            await self._read_comms(queue)
            await self._process_comms(queue)
            if self.update_rate != 0:
                time.sleep(self.update_rate)
```

I must say that I am really new to asyncio (I started for this project).
And I am pretty sure that I do a lot of stupid stuff there.

The problem with this code, is that I never get outside of the first loop in process_comms().
Which was to be expected but I am looking for an solution for what I am trying to do here.

Which is as a summary to have two concurrent loop that use the Queue as a buffer. One to feed the queue, the other one to process it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, solved my problem !

For those that might encounter same problem :

I solved that by using :

```
queue = asyncio.Queue()
await asyncio.gather(self._read_comms(queue),self._process_comms(queue))
```

Comment: For the record, in this specific case, you could have just done: `reader = asyncio.create_task(self._read_comms(queue))` (without `await`), `await self._process_comms(queue)`, `await reader`. `gather` is a nice short-hand (and superior to my alternate code), but fundamentally, your problem is that you tried to `await` the first task before you launched the second, which meant the first task had to run to completion before the second even got launched (leading to potentially huge queues building up, and nothing ever getting processed if the connection nevers gets closed by the server).

Comment: Note that in some cases (including this one), you may want to use `asyncio.wait` or `asyncio.as_completed`; if `gather` has an awaitable that never finishes it will never finish either. `_process_comms` appears to run forever (blocking on an empty queue), so you'd need to either add a sentinel value that `_read_comms` could send when the connection is broken so `_process_comms` knows to finish, or you'd want to use `wait` with `asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED` so it resumes running when either task completes.